# MV command deleted file?

Tags: command-line, bash, copy, mv

Have an odd occurrence (or at least I think? still pretty green in linux) where I tried running the `mv` to move a `.png` file to my `Pictures` directory, I copied the command directly from the terminal from when I ran the `mv` command:

```
$ sudo mv Firefox_wallpaper.png /Pictures
```

I would assume the file gets essentially cut and pasted into the Pictures directory.

File original location: `/home/ebeeze`
What I would assume after the MV command: `/home/ebeeze/Pictures`

Any help would be nice, not sure if I have permission to see it (ran `sudo ls -a` but nothing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you put a "/" before picture. this makes it an absolute path

Your picture is now /Pictures in the root of the drive.

The command you wanted was:

```
 mv Firefox_wallpaper.png Pictures/
```

Note: `sudo` is normally not needed, unless writing to root owned folders or files. For most everyday tasks, it should not be used since root privileges poses a security risk.

Comment: `mv Firefox_wallpaper.png Pictures` also works, `mv` is wise enough not to overwrite the directory but to write into it.

Comment: God bless you ravery, really appreciate such a quick response, cheers!!

Comment: @dessert -- adding "/" to designate a directory will prevent `mv` from renaming the file if you mistype the directory name. Am I correct in this assumption.

Comment: @ravery Yes, and generally it's the way to do – I just wanted to add that OP didn't do it wrong in this particular account. By the way, to be sure one would just type `Pic`, press <Tab> and let `bash` care for the correct spelling and the slash. :)